# getting a registered osgi service with Reference annotation or bundleContext

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I an refactoring existing OSGI APIs. There is an instance variable (emailHandler) declared with 'final' keyword which is initialized inside the constructor. The instantiation of the instance needs an OSGI service, but I think that constructor is called before osgi service binding takes place, but the OSGI service that I need is already registered by other bundle. Is there a way to get this OSGI service?

Here is my sample code.

```
  private final EmailHandler emailHandler;
  private final DatabaseStorage databaseStorage;


  private IEmailService emailService;

  @Component(service = SampleOSGIService.class)
  public SampleOSGIService() {
    this.emailHandler = new EmailHandler(emailService);
    this.databaseStorage = this.emailHandler.getDatabaseStorage();
  }
  
  @Reference
  public void bindEmailService(IEmailService emailService) {
    this.emailService = emailService;
  }
```

I need to get 'IEmailService' OSGI service in order to initialize 'emailHandler'.

Or do i need to remove 'final' keyword and instantiate 'emailHandler' and 'databaseStorage' outside the constructor after the 'SampleOSGIService' is activated?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `final` then you can use *constructor* injection.

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    final Bar bar;

    public Foo( @Reference Bar bar ) {
       this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Anyway, the bind methods should only be used in rare circumstances. Use field references instead:

```
@Reference
Bar bar;
```

A lot has happened in OSGi in the last few years!

Comment: Sorry.. BTW, 'SampleOSGIService' is OSGI service, too. so it's not directly invoked by any class from my APIs.